# Calling a txt list from within another txt list c#

Tags: c#, list

I have six txt files. And one of them holding the others names in inside. For example i have a txt file called brands. And inside of brands there are names of cars brands for example: bmv, toyota, audi...
And also there are files who exactly same names (bmv.txt, toyota.txt, audi.txt).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLnh4.png)
(Sorry for my english its not my native language)

My questions is can i create arrays for each car using for loop?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. This is not a homework writing service. Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is rather vague, I will give you a basic flow for what you need to do.

1. Read File names for each category and store them.
2. Then Read the Contents of each category and match the values with the filenames.
3. Read Contents of each sub category file.

You are going to use the following Code Samples to Achieve this.

Get Filenames in Directory:

`string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory);`

Read Contents of File:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
 {
     string line;
     // Read and display lines from the file until the end of
     // the file is reached.
     while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(line);
      }
 }
```

This is a basic approach that should get you started.

Good Luck.